# tSQLt - How to output a custom failure or success message?

Tags: tsqlt

We are using the tSQLt framework and have the below code in the test.

```
IF @count>0
    EXEC tsqlt.fail;
else EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 1,1;
```

I am interested to know how we can display a custom test success or failure message when this test gets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tSQLt.fail takes up to 10 parameters that all get concatenated into a custom failure message.

You also do not need the call to tSQLt.AssertEquals as it, in your case, literally does nothing.

BTW, asserting a count is in almost all cases a bad idea, as it does not really tell you anything about the result. If you get the correct count back, you could still have wrong data. And if you get the incorrect count, you don't have any additional info on what went wrong.

Have a look at tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable or tSQLt.AssertEmptyTable instead.

Comment: So, do you mean that if I omit AssertEquals in a test, then it is equivalant to test success?

Comment: @variable Sebastian means that the test succeed when it does not throw exception. In your case AssertEquals 1,1 will always pass as 1==1 and will never throw the exception, so there is no point in that part of code at all.

Comment: My test code is a select statement that returns a value in the @count variable (based on SQL SELECT WHERE statement). Then the code checks if the variable has value of 0 or not. If 0 then it will go to the else loop and pass the test (since there is no pass command so I had to use the AsserEquals 1,1); where as if >0 then it will fail the test (using the fail command).